# Basically I'm trying to add an EventListener for resize and

Tags: reactjs, render, react-hooks

So here is the code ...

```
function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height
  };
}
```

```
 let minNumberOfCards = Math.round(window.innerWidth / 120);
 const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = React.useState(getWindowDimensions());

    React.useEffect(() => {
      function handleResize() {
        setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
      }

      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, [windowDimensions,]);
```

The issue I'm facing is that I need to compute the number of  cards to be displayed and I get the a really messy result :|. Since addEventListener is an async thingy. 
What I tried is `minNumberOfCards = Math.round(windowDimensions.width/ 120);`
buuuut again since it's async I get the correct number after a while time when my initial numbers I set kicks in. Basically I've set a var minNumberOfCards to be default 9 ( for example ).

The expected result would be to have the minNumberOfCards depending on the screen width. That's it !!!!! Any ideas/solutions on how can I achieve this without causing lots of re-renderings ?

Answer (score 1):

Its a perfect use case for [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) or [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle):

```
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const App = () => {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState('Change Window Size');

  const [minNumberOfCards, setMinNumberOfCards] = useState(
    Math.round(window.innerWidth / 120)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    // Better add a listener and only change the minNumberOfCards
  },[...]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(handleResize, 500);

    window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedHandleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, [windowDimensions]);
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(windowDimensions, null, 2)}</pre>
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

Try changing the window size in the next sandbox:

[image: Edit react-antd-styled-template]

Please refer to [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/)

Comment: Almost good but I have the same issue with the first render since I don't nave a static value to give to minNumberOfCards and if I give it innerWidth.width it will render again stupid things .... :( I've just tried it :(

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Dennis Vash I don't get the minimal thingy :))

Comment: So I've updated the question ... the thing is that the first render would fail computing the number of cards till it guesses the width :( I really need a solution for this... thanks Dennis!

Comment: Did you read how to create a producible example? I updated the sandbox although your question is not clear.

Comment: Why you just don't use the minNumberOfCards as a state? instead using window dimensions